# Too large fonts on mobile

Tags: bug, style, mobile

Font sizes on Super User are way to big on mobile devices (or, more specifically: viewports with widths up to 640 px). This does not affect all Stack Exchange sites, it’s a problem with the Super User theme.

[image: Super User vs Meta]

The problem appears to stem from a bad interaction with the `<body>` font size and other elements referencing it using the `rem` unit.

On Meta, the font size is simply `11px`. However, on Super User, it is `calc(var(--su-static12) - var(--su-static1))`. Dunno what’s the point, the result (when looking at calculated values) is also 11 px. Either way, the result is very different.

I can see the issue in the following environments:

- Firefox simulated mobile view (origin of screenshots above)
- Edge simulated mobile view
- Safari in iOS

I suggest sticking with a `11px` here, the `calc()` stuff seems pointless to me.

Comment: Meta.SE duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391579/mobile-font-size-way-too-large From experience clearing your caches on mobile can fix it.

Comment: Nope, Super User is still pulling the CSS that causes this. // But good to know the fix is already on its way.

Comment: Weird. Firefox mobile was faulty for me yesterday and literally fixed after clearing caches. Maybe a "simulated view" problem?

Comment: Maybe German traffic is handled on a different node in the CDN or something.

Comment: Can confirm - I saw the original issue on SO and saw it fixed, but I can still reproduce this in SU. Curiously, this happens with my Samsung Internet browser, but not with Chrome or Firefox on the same phone. My gut instinct says "caching", but no amount of refresh/restarts solves this.

Comment: For the record: Also still happening over here. Maybe the version in the URL needs to be updated or something? Even when I fetch the CSS using `curl`, I still get the buggy version.

Comment: Adding a datapoint regarding CDNs - I'm from Israel. I observed this behavior both on my mobile network and from my home's wifi (although they probably use the same CDN)

Comment: This seems to be resolved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fix discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391582) is finally live where I live. Hopefully the rest of the world also has it!

> **tl;dr**: This bug has been [patched in our design system](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/commit/ebee94060f5eed2bc1950210565e6110a6dd3ef1) and the [update](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases/tag/v1.10.1) has been shipped to production.
>
> ---
>
> Good catch @0stone0!
>
> This was due to a change to some `font-size` values to replace explicit pixel values with calculated values based on custom properties. To be honest, I'm not sure why the calculated values cause this issue and explicit pixel values don't. Nevertheless, changing back to explicit pixel values resolves the issue.
>
> **Note**: The cache on each network site needs to clear individually, so this may take a few days to be reflected.